# Imported csv file from Mapinfo does not show any field related to color

Tags: mapinfo

I want to know how the color scheme works for imported file in Mapinfo.

I have a number of sites and links in Pathloss (they are colored in red and green for sites and links (e.g. On air and Not on air sites). I have exported them for Mapinfo. Mapinfo is showing the same color for sites and links as it was in Pathloss. It works good until now.

Now, I want to work with the thematic map (I need to show the legend of this layer as well as other layers) but can't find how can I choose the sites/links colorwise ( I have no column that shows on air/not on air or green/red or 0/1).

Is there anyway I can play with the data that is imported from Pathloss in thematic map?

Is there anyway to differentiate the sites in thematic map based on the color scheme they are using?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about polygons and line/polyline items you can extract the colour information with the following:

1) Create a new column of data type Integer in your base table, let's call it `MyColour` for this example

2) Select all the polygon objects from your table: `Select * from YourTable Where Str$(obj) = "Region" Into MyPolygons`

3) Update the MyPolygons query results with the style information:
  - `Update Table MyPolygons Set MyColour = StyleAttr(ObjectInfo(obj, 3), 2)`

4) Select all the line/polyline objects from your table: `Select * from YourTable Where Str$(obj) In ("Line", "Polyline") Into MyLines`

5) Update the MyLines query results with the style information: `Update Table MyLines Set MyColour = StyleAttr(ObjectInfo(obj, 2), 4)`

Your base table should now have a column, `MyColour` in this example, which has been updated with the (forecolour) Integer colour codes for the associated object. You can now use that column to apply some sort of thematic style based upon the different colour attributes.